# I can't get countif to find text in vba

Tags: countif

I am trying to find the number of rows in a column that contain the letters "wand". I am using this code:

```
Dim wand As Integer
wands = Application.CountIf(Range("b:b"), "WAND*")
```

I think I am telling it to look in Column B for any row that has the letters "wand". It returns 0 every time and I know there are several rows with those letters.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try `"*WAND*"` instead of `"WAND"`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew - I got it to work